# series converges but not absolutely

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $a_n = \frac{ i^n}{n} $ where $i = \sqrt{-1} $. It is clear that $\sum |a_n| = \sum \frac{1}{n} $ diverges. But, how about $\sum a_n $, does it converge ?

Obviously, using the ratio test, gives an inconclusive result. I was trying to show that its partial sums $S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{ i^n}{n } $ converges: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, then

$$ \left| S_k - 0 \right| = \left| \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{i^n}{n} \right| \leq \sum \left|\frac{ i^n}{n}\right|  = \sum \frac{1}{n} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + ... + \frac{1}{k}$$

But, I got stuck trying to prove the last expression is less that $\epsilon $. Perhaps I need a better choice of $N$ ?

Comment: You should consider even and odd terms separately, in order to separate the real and imaginary parts of the sum. Then, you should find something quite reminiscent of sums like $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}n$...

Comment: Alternating thinking required...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By the Alternating Series Test you know that

$$
    \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{i^{2k}}{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{i^{2k+1}}{2k+1} = i \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
$$

both converge. Use this and other algebraic properties of series to conclude that the given series converges.